# Errors were encountered while processing: distro-info-data

Tags: 16.04, apt, dpkg

I'm trying to install aptitude package by using the command:

```
 sudo apt-get install aptitude
```

but installation is getting terminated and is returning the following errors:

```
dpkg: error processing package distro-info-data (--configure):
package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration.  
Errors were encountered while processing:
distro-info-data  
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Please can anyone tell me how to fix this error?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: I'm using 16.04

Comment: Did you follow the given advice and try `sudo apt install --reinstall distro-info-data`  ?